# Random sample from discrete distribution. Find an unbiased estimator.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$X$ is a discrete random variable with parameter $a > 0$ whose pmf is defined as:
$$
f_X(x) = \begin{cases}0.2, &x = a\\0.3, &x = 6a\\0.5, &x = 10a\end{cases}
$$
Say we have a random sample of length $n$ of $n$ independent, identically distributed random variables with the distribution of $X$.

I need to find an unbiased estimator ($\operatorname{E}[\,\hat{\theta}\,] = \theta$) for $a$.

We know that $\operatorname{E}[X] = 7a$, and we could say $\operatorname{E}[\frac{1}{7}\cdot\overline{X}] = a$.

So, is $\frac{1}{7}\cdot\overline{X}$ an unbiased estimator for $a$?

Comment: Yes, it is an unbiased estimator for $a$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: thank you very much. Just curious. Suppose I want to use maximum likelihood. What would be the cumulative pmf to use?

Comment: Offhand I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

Let $N$ denote the number of different results in a sample $S$ of size $n$. If $N=1$ and the unique observed result is $X$, then the parameter $a$ is in $\{X,X/6,X/10\}$ and the likelihood of the sample if $a=X/k$ is $(p_k)^n$ where $(p_1,p_6,p_{10})=(.2,.3,.5)$. Thus, the MLE estimator is $\widehat a=X/10$.

If $N\geqslant2$, then let $X\ne Y$ denote two results in $S$, say with $X\gt Y$. Then the funny thing is that $a$ is *known exactly and with full probability* since only one likelihood is not zero. Namely, $X/Y$ is either $10$ or $6$ or $5/3$ (all other ratios being impossible), in which cases $\widehat a=X/10=Y$ or $\widehat a=X/6=Y$ or $\widehat a=X/10=Y/6$ respectively. And, as already said, on the event $[N\gt1]$, $\widehat a=a$ almost surely.