# Finding an unbiased estimator for a parameter, dicrete variable

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables, expectation

Let $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{N}$ be a random variable. Define $p_i =  P(X=i), \ \ i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Find an unbiased and consistent estimator for $p_1$.

I need to find an estimator $\alpha_n(X_1 + ... + X_n)$ for which I would have $\mathbb{E} \alpha_n = p_1$ and $\alpha_n \to p_1$ in probability or almost surely.

I've found this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598649/random-sample-from-discrete-distribution-find-an-unbiased-estimator) but this isn't helpful.

Could you tell me how to look for estimators of a given parameter?

Comment: A natural estimator is to count the number of times the random variable is equal to $1$ and divide by the sample size. Would that meet the requirements of the question?

Comment: @Henry I don't know. I suppose it would be close to arithmetic mean of those $n$ variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer with the simplest notation I can manage. Maybe you can match
ideas here with the content of the previous Answer by @r.e.s.

You want to estimate the probability $p_1$ that $X = 1$ based on a sample of $n$ independent observations from the distribution of $X$.
You count $Y_n$, the number of instances among $n$ in which $X = 1.$
Then $Y_n \sim Bin(n, p_1)$. Then an unbiased, consistent estimator of $p_1$ is $\alpha_n = Y_n/n.$ From what you may know about binomial random variables, I suppose you can prove the two necessary
relationships for 'unbiased' and 'consistent.'

If you want a concrete situation to think about, imagine being given a die that may or may not be fair. By rolling it $n$ times you want to estimate the probability that the die comes up "1".

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Could you tell me if my calculations are right? $$\mathbb{E} \alpha_n=\frac{np_1}{n}=p_1.$$ When it comes to convergence, how can I prove that $$\frac{X_n}{n} \to p_1$$ almost surely?

Comment: Unbiassedness looks OK. Don't know the structure of the course. If you've had the Law of Large Numbers, this is usually the first application of it.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: *Proportions* are intuitive estimators of *probabilities*; i.e., to estimate $P(X \in A)$ given i.i.d. observations $X_1,...,X_n$ of $X$, consider the proportion of the $n$ observations that are in $A$: 
$$\hat{P}(X\in A) = \frac{1_{X_1\in A} + 1_{X_2\in A} +\ ... +\ 1_{X_n\in A}}{n},
$$
where 
$$1_E = 
\begin{cases} 
1,  & \text{if E occurs} \\
0, &\text{otherwise.} 
\end{cases} 
$$

NB: Although you wrote that the estimator should be a function of $X_1 + ... + X_n$, I assume this should be $X_1, ..., X_n$.